# Batch file to look for files under a specific subfolder

Tags: batch

Dear Batch Script experts,

I have the following files (too many of them):

```
F:\ABC\NAME1\2018\Q2\07 JUL\RANDOM NUMBER1\MSG.DAT
F:\ABC\NAME2\2018\Q3\07 JUL\RANDOM NUMBER2\MSG.DAT
F:\ABC\NAMEA\2018\Q3\08 AUG\RANDOM NUMBER3\MSG.DAT
F:\ABC\NAMEB\2018\Q3\09 SEP\RANDOM NUMBER4\MSG.DAT
F:\ABC\NAME3\2018\Q4\09 SEP\RANDOM NUMBER5\MSG.DAT
```

I am trying to execute a program (program1.exe) from a batch file and provide the file path (the required full path) as a command line argument.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program1.exe" "the required full path"
```

I am struggling to find the URL for MSG.DAT files under a subfolder Q3 for example.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By "URL" do you mean the "full path"?

Comment: yes, I've just edited/corrected it. thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch you will have to split the task into 2 parts,

- 1st finding folders q3 with `for /r /d` (a pseudo wildcard is neccessary)
- 2nd iterating them and searching FILE MSG.DAT recursively

---

```
@Echo off
For /r "F:\" /D %%A in (Q3?) Do For /F "delims=" %%B in (
   'Dir /B /S "%%A\MSG.DAT" 2^>NUL '
) Do Echo "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program1.exe" "%%~fB"
pause
```

If the output looks OK, remove the echo in the 2nd last line.

Comment: Many thanks for that. It doesn't work with @echo off and Do Echo. I got rid of both and now it works. LotPings thank you very much.